# jquery addclass

Tags: jquery

This is probably simple but I am new at jQuery so... In IE 8 the link color does not turn pink even in compatibility mode. Now if I run it on firefox,chrome it works.  But here is the thing that baffles me.  If I add an alert to the function then in IE 8 the link turns pink and the message box displays.  Can someone please explain what is going on here?

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
a.over {color:pink;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").mouseover(function () {
            $(this).addClass("over");
            //alert("mouseOver");
        });

        $("a").mouseout(function () {
            $(this).removeClass("over");

        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <a class="" href="#">Link</a>
    </div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I know I can probably just add something like a:hover to my css but this is just a text book example that I can not get to work.

Thank you

Comment: I don't see why it would not work. Try changing the CSS to `a.over, a:visited.over, a:link.over {color:pink;}` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: For IE @Kanishka solution did work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding the doctype  beggning of your page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

UPDATE

```
The doctype declaration should be the very first thing in an HTML document, before the <html> tag.

The doctype declaration is not an HTML tag; it is an instruction to the web browser about what version of the markup language the page is written in.

The doctype declaration refers to a Document Type Definition (DTD). The DTD specifies the rules for the markup language, so that the browsers render the content correctly.
```

Comment: i try to give you a point up and I get the message (click on this box to dismiss)... just having a bad day.  Anyway that worked.  Now do you know why that is so important to IE and also why adding an alert to the code made it work?

Answer (score 3):

I know you're probably not asking this, but just using a `:hover` pseudo-class would work :)

```
a:hover { color: pink; }
```

Also, consider using the [jQ `hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method and the [jQ `toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('over');
},
function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('over');
});
```

But I also agree with @Kanishka: using the correct `DOCTYPE` is imperative for IE

Comment: Thank you for the hover function.  I thought I read some where that hover was not as reliable cross browser as mouseover mouseout.  But I could be wrong.